# JAVASCRIPT - if last character is : (colon), change font weight

Tags: javascript, fonts

Is it possible to change font weight if last character is colon with JavaScript?

I have site, where people can add recipe. And i want to highlight parts of ingredients of recipe. For example:

**topping:**
-chocolate
-milk
**filling:**
-...
-...

I searched and i found that codes:

for last character

```
if (myString.charAt(myString.length - 1) == ':')
```

and for weight change

```
function changeWeight(600)
{

document.getElementById("id_1").style.fontWeight = fontWeight;

}
```

I do not know how to write the code to work. I am beginner.

Thank you very much.

Comment: *"Is it possible"* - yes. As to how, you already have it (just a little more effort). Just merge both codes.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
if (myString.charAt(myString.length - 1) == ':') {
    changeWeight("600");
}

function changeWeight(weight) {
    document.getElementById("id_1").style.fontWeight = weight;
}
```

Comment: Also, I would highly recommend that you change `if (myString.charAt(myString.length - 1) == ':') {` to `if (myString.charAt(myString.length - 1) === ':') {`

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you want to make specific text bold, not all text within an element. You would need to get the text out of the element, change it, and put it back.

You can use code like this to but a bold tag around all words in the element that ends with a colon:

```
var element = document.getElementById("id_1");
var text = element.innerHTML;

text = text.replace(/([A-Za-z]+:)/g, '<strong>$1</strong>');

element.innerHTML = text;
```

Note: For that to work properly, you can't have other HTML elements inside the element that has words with colons in the actual markup. I you have for example `<a href="http://stackoverflow.com">SO</a>` in the code, it would break because of the `http:` in the link.

If you have that single word alone in an element, you would get the text and check for the colon:

```
var element = document.getElementById("id_1");
var text = element.innerHTML;

if (text.charAt(text.length - 1)) == ':') {
  element.style.fontWeight = 'bold';
}
```